# jQuery Validate Ignore elements with style

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate for client side validation and I want to ignore any element that has the `style="display: none"`

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: "?"
});
```

What would my selector be for that in the above case?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Note:** As of version 1.9.0, `ignore: ":hidden"` is the default option, so it does not have to be set explicitly anymore.

---

Use [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/):

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - **They have a display value of none.**
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

---

**Update:** for completeness, from the [plugin's documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

> **ignore**
>   Elements to ignore when validating, simply filtering them out. jQuery's **not**-method is used, therefore everything that is accepted by `not()` can be passed as this option. Inputs of type submit and reset are always ignored, so are disabled elements.

Comment: @Felix: Is there a way to get validate() to return a boolean value?

Comment: @gmcalab: What should this value indicate? It returns a `Validator`: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validator

Comment: @Felix thanks, nice link! Right now the form() is still not validate, its still validating the hidden fields....

Comment: So instead of ignoring the hidden elements, I disabled the hidden elements and it seems to work now.

Comment: @gmcalab: Good to hear that :) Don't know why it does not work with `:hidden`. As `.not()` takes any selector, this should work too.

Comment: @Felix, yea I am not sure why it wont work with `:hidden`...how would you implement the `not()`

Comment: @gmcalab: I am not sure what you mean. `not()` is a function provided by jQuery.

Comment: @Felix, I know that `not()` is provided by jQuery but I guess I thought you were giving an alternative to using `:hidden`, so I was asking for the implementation.

Comment: @Felix: I suppose :hidden is not working because the behaviour of :hidden changed in jQuery 1.4.2: non-visible elements that still consume space (visibility:hidden css property) aren't considered "hidden"

Comment: @Felix you're my hero!  I had been using ignore: ".ignore" and manually adding it to all my hidden elements.  As you can imagine this was just stupid when I had multiple input elements under a single hidden element.  THANK YOU!  selectors are my friend:)

Comment: Still I want to validate the hidden fields, but i don't want to show the success image for those hidden fields.. Is there any way..?

Comment: Note that `ignore: ":hidden"` is the default! To undo this functionality, use `ignore: ""`

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the info! I had a look and it seems that `:hidden` was set in version 1.9.0 (which was released a year, but after I answered).

Comment: A slight old topic, but I've just had this issue, well kind of. I needed to validate an input which is hidden by default (a select element that has `display:none` due to being styled with Select2), so thanks Felix and Peter for the useful info.

Comment: A bug was reported with the ignore class not working on focus out. Is this still an issue? https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/156 I got around it by disabling validation on focus out e.g. $myForm.validate({ onfocusout: false })

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling. If anyone wants this restored by default, you need to set the defaults using `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: "" });`

Answer (score 5):

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

`":hidden"`

is what your looking for.

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a display value of none.
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

I feel this might be better.

Comment: Why would I want to ignore the visible fields?

Comment: Whoops, I was thinking to put a not() around it but I just saw hidden, changed.