# How do you ignore hidden page elements when validating using jquery.validationEngine.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, client-side-validation

I have a div who's style defaults to "display: none" until a previous field has been filled out, and it contains a drop down list that requires a selection.

If the page is submitted before this div becomes visible, the validation error appears to the left half-off the page.

This is not a functional problem of course, but I've been wondering if there's a way to have the validation engine ignore hidden elements.

So far I've tried class="validate[optional: Special]" as pointed out on the [creator's blog](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/): "optional: Special: Only validate when the field is not empty *Please call optional first". It doesn't seem to work as suggested.

```
<div id="container" style="display: none;">
   ...
   <select id="mapLocation" onchange="moveMapToCenter();" class="validate[optional: Special]" />
   ...
</div>
```

I've also tried using jquery.validate "ignore":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#aspnetForm").validationEngine({
      ignore: ":hidden"
      success: false,
      failure: function() {}
   })
});
```

This may be a simple oversight on my part, we'll see! Thanks.

Comment: How are you "hiding" your elements?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623514/jquery-validate-ignore-elements-with-style : "Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
They have a display value of none.
They are form elements with type="hidden".
Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Comment: And if you actually technically mean "how" I'm hiding them - once a postal code field has been filled out and validated I show the element with "display: inherit;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding and removing the validation[required] class attribute through functions that hide and show the element.

```
function showContainer() {
   ...
   $("#mapLocation").addClass("validate[required]");
   ...
}
function hideContainer() {
   ...
   $("#mapLocation").removeClass("validate[required]");
}
```

This works fairly well to avoid validation error messages showing up in strange places when hiding page elements that require validation.

Answer (score 0):

i need disable temporary more fields, i make this, a pretty solution:
a little jquery extension:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn, {
    switchValidationEngine: function (enable) {
        $.each(this, function (i, n) {
            var field = $(n);
            var rulesParsing = field.attr("class");
            var newVal = enable ? rulesParsing.replace(/validate_not\[/g, "validate[") : rulesParsing.replace(/validate\[/g, "validate_not[");
            field.attr("class", newVal);
        });
    }
});
```

usage to disable a field validation:

> $("#txtModel").switchValidationEngine(false);

usage to re-enable a field validation:

> $("#txtModel").switchValidationEngine(true);