# jQuery Validation Plugin not validating fields in a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have the following div block which i'm trying to validate using the jQuery validation plugin

```
<div class="row" id="signupaddress1" hidden>
    <label for="id-31"><span>Address 1:</span><span class="mark">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="required" id="id-31" name="address1"/>
</div>
```

Then using

```
$("#form").validate(...);
```

to validate the form. But if this div is hidden it appears to ignore the field when validating. The form uses a postcode lookup to populate the address fields and then displays the div when this has been populated but, as a result, if only the postcode is entered the form can be submitted without validating address1 contains anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623514/jquery-validate-ignore-elements-with-style

Comment: Nope that's the opposite of the problem. It appears not be be validating and this option hasn't been set on the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using the new validator plugin which ignores hidden fields by default.  To overwrite that just use this and it will work.

```
ignore:""
```

You can refer to the Github repo for the change [Changeset](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/21707129666012f6b0bc60622eb3bcb9f87daa04)

Answer (score 0):

You are telling jQuery to validate the form but where is your form tag you should do something like this

```
<form><div class="row" id="signupaddress1" hidden>
<label for="id-31"><span>Address 1:</span><span class="mark">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="required" id="id-31" name="address1"/></div></form>
```

than use

```
$("form").validate(...);
```