# How to show required field validation conditionally from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

In My MVC 4 application, I have a **Multi Select List Box**, where I can select multiple values, I also has an Item **New Role** as one of the list items, which also refers to a model property **NewRole**.

So using Jquery whenever the user selections contain New Role, I will provide a text box to the user, which is bind to NewRole from model as given,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewRole)
```

Which also has the following evaluation field.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewRole)
```

And I will hide this text-box if the user selected options does not has the Item **New Role**.

Now the problem is even if I hide the div which contain the Text Box, it will try evaluating the required field validation.

What I require is When User Selects New Role and the User did not enter anything in the provided text Box then validate the required field property.

I know I can write a JQuery to show an alert when the div visible and does't has any value. But I want this default validation should happen on that condition.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the trick to avid certain client side validation conditionally ... you can use the IGNORE attribute of the validation ...

[jQuery Validate Ignore elements with style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623514/jquery-validate-ignore-elements-with-style)

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

If this is not what you are looking ... I will provide more specific information

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with RemoteAttribute. Take a look at this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Keep in mind that this is NOT client side validation meaning there is an actual server post happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the rules add and remove, when new role is selected add new rule which validates the textbox on other selection remove the rule from text box and hide it like you are doing:

http://validation.bassistance.de/rules/