# How can I disable the required attribute when submitting a form

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am new to this so the answer may be obvious, so apologies if it is.

I have created form to add a new customer. The person entering the new user first needs to check whether the customer is a company or individual in order to toggle different fields to be completed. I am using Bootstrap to develop the form and have included the `required` attribute against specific fields.  When I submit the form nothing happens and I receive an error stating **An invalid form control with name='user-firstname' is not focusable.**.  This field has the `required` attribute as well as being hidden.  I am guessing this is what is causing the issue.

I have tried to remove the `required` attribute however am struggling to make reference to the correct element. Below is part of my code:

```
<div class="container hidden-form">
        <form class="needs-validation">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="user-type" id="radio-company" value="Company" checked>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-company">Company</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="user-type" id="radio-individual" value="Individual">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-individual">Individual</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group company-field">
                        <label for="user-companyname">Company Name*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-companyname" name="user-companyname" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group individual-field hidden-field">
                        <label for="user-firstname">First Name*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control required-entry" id="user-firstname" name="user-firstname" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group individual-field hidden-field">
                        <label for="user-surname">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-surname" name="user-surname">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

My Jquery code is:

```
$("#radio-company").click(function() {
    $(".individual-field.required-entry").removeAttr("required");
    $(".company-field").removeClass("hidden-field");
    $(".individual-field").addClass("hidden-field");            
});
```

I know one answer is to have a separate form for a Company or Individual, but that seems to potentially double the maintenance of the form and also means that if a person clicks on the radio button to change the user type they would need to re-enter all the information again as a new form would be displayed.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us hidden-field css definition? Also, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623514/jquery-validate-ignore-elements-with-style and also https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/4gj253/why_isnt_jqueryvalidate_ignoring_hidden_fields/. Might give you some clue.

Comment: Add a jsfiddle to your question.. It helps and save time a lot to those who try to help you..

Comment: Going by your code, I think you are trying to remove `required` from the input with id `user-firstname`; the code you show has a selector which will not match that element.  The easiest way is to use that ID!  The jQuery selector would be `$('#user-firstname')`.  As to why what you have does not work - `.individual-field.required-entry` would match a single element with both those classes.  Just adding a space between them would work: `$('.individual-field .required-entry')`, as that means "any element with class `required-entry` contained by another element with class `individual-field`".

Comment: sam - couldn't access the reddit post but the other one would indicate that I shouldn't have the issue I am.  Thanks for the lead as will investigate further.

Comment: Don't Panic - thanks for the tip.  I'm now accessing the required element as hoped.  Will need to investigate further why I even need to remove the attribute given the lead sam gave me, but at least I now appear to have a work around until I understand better